# How to resolve a state from URL using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

If I have something like this:

{`ui-sref="tab({tabid:3})"`}

Clicking on the element with the above attribute will trigger a state with URL something like this `/tab/:tabid`.

For example, `http://..../tab/3`

Now my problem:

I have a list of tabs implemented using angular-material. Refer this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/MmUAgp37Bl0vzaqrF0jY?p=preview)

When I click on `Tab1` the state is `/tab/1`. When I click on `Tab2` the state is `/tab/2`. All these state changes occur with click. But now if I manually change the URL, say I type in the address bar `http://..../tab/3`, I want the corresponding state change to happen and `Tab3` should be activated. At present, suppose I am on Tab3 and I manually change the URL to '..../tab/2', it doesn't activate Tab2, although the state is changed.

Is there a simple way to resolve states from the URL by considering the state parameters?

Comment: demos have example...see http://codepen.io/Mmatiasn/pen/GomQLW

Comment: I don't think that's possible. All these are actually one state `/tab` with different parameters. You inject the `id` parameter and set the tab index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main concern here is the use of tabs. The first tab belongs to one state and the remaining tabs belong to another state, each tab uniquely identified by an ID that is available through state parameter. So although the correct state is resolved when I manually change the URL, the correct tab is not not made active. The simplest workaround is to read in the state parameter using `$stateParams` and set the `md-selected` attribute of angular-material to activate the corresponding tab.